# Alinha texto do bootstrap navbar verticalmente

Tags: css

Estou usando em meu projeto duas `navbar` e estou com um problema para alinhar o texto do primeiro menu na vertical, tentei criar uma estrutura para alterar mas não obtive sucesso, o que tenho é isso:

Primeira `Navbar`:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="MenuUm">
      <div class="search-side"> <a href="#" class="show-search"><i class="icon-search-1"></i></a>
        <div class="search-form">
          <form autocomplete="off" role="search" method="POST" class="searchform" action="resultado.php">
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Buscar...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Início da Lista de Navegação-->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="catalogos.php">catálogos e manuais</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="cores.php">cores e linha</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="garantia.php">garantia e uso</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Segunda `Navbar`:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="MenuDois"> 
      <!-- Início da Lista de Navegação-->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="index.php">INÍCIO</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="empresa.php">EMPRESA</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="produtos.php">PRODUTOS</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="representantes.php">REPRESENTANTES</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="encontrar.php">ONDE ENCONTRAR</a> </li>
        <li><a href="contato.php">CONTATO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

O `css` das `Navbar` está assim:

```
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

O que tentei fazer foi criar duas estruturas diferentes para cada `Navbar`, ficando assim, mas como disse, não deu certo.

```
.navbar-nav-1 > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav-2 > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Para ficar mais fácil de entender vou anexar uma imagem do que estou tentando fazer, vejam:
[Exemplo do que preciso](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/imagens/imagem.fw.png)

O site em desenvolvimento é esse:
[Site](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/index.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o uso de [Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) do bootstrap da para fazer este menu sem css adicional.

**Passo a passo:**

1º - Adicionei um `container` para centralizar

2° - Adicionei 1 `row` geral dividida em 4|8, a de 4 ficará com o logo a de 8 os menus.

3° - Adicionei a logo normalmente dentro do `col-md-4`.

4º - Adicionei cada menu em uma row dentro do `col-md-8` ,
 cada menu recebeu o `pull-right`, para ficar alinhado a direita.

**Exemplo:**

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <img src="http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/images/anc.fw.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

           <!--  MENU AQUI 1-->
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-11 pull-right">
                 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Catálogos e manuais</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cores e linha </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Garantia e uso </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                       <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                          <div class="input-group">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar..." name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                             <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </form>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>

           <!--  MENU AQUI 2 -->
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">INÍCIO </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">EMPRESA </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">PRODUTOS </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">REPRESENTANTES </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ONDE ENCONTRAR </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>

        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**Como ficou:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Veja no jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/dmqqfu5a/show/)

Comment: Olá @GabrielRodrigues, obrigado pela ajuda, mas estou com um problema quando a página é redimensionada, os navbar-toggle não estão sendo exibidos, pelo que que vi, no seu exemplo eles foram suprimidos.

Comment: @adventistapr acontece que esta navegação é feito pela simples nav e não navbar, ela ira ficar bem formatado da resolução  1230×600 para cima, se você quiser um menu responsivo ai você podera adicionar um media para mostrar o menu responsivo em uma resolução inferior.

Answer (score 2):

No style.css, na class `search-side` adicione a propriedade `margin-top` com `15px`

```
.search-side {
    margin-top: -15px !important;
}
```

Na primeira `navbar` defina um nome de classe como `navbar-primeira` e adicione a propriedade

```
.navbar-primeira { 
   margin-top: 35px !important; 
}
```

E para a segunda `navbar` adicione as propriedades

```
ul li a { 
    max-height: 55px !important; 
    margin-top: -15px !important;
}
```

E por fim, na `div` com a classe `hidden-header`, remova o atributo `style="height: 161px;"` que foi setado diretamente no `html`.

Deixei ativado o outline, mas é isso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @DouglasGaldino, obrigado pela resposta, estou tentando alterar de acordo com o que você indicou mas não estou conseguindo obter o resultado que você teve, o que está na imagem de sua resposta.

Comment: Eu utilizei seu site para realizar as alterações, diretamente no chrome. Você alterou alguma coisa após o dia 04/01?

Comment: Havia enviado uma atualização sem o outline e sem o style="height: 161px;", a sua resposta foi a que chegou mais perto da solução que preciso.

Comment: Alterei os valores do post, tenta replicar novamente.

Comment: Acabei de alterar as informações, mas as a primeira navbar está ficando com um fundo cinza e o campo de busca desalinhado, por favor, acesse:
http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/index.php

Comment: Coloca o input ao lado do icone, os demais é alterar os valores passados para corresponder a posição correta.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo site que você passou, creio que seria interessante rever a estrutura do seu header pois o framework bootstrap não foi feito para manter 2 navbar um dentro do outro. Pelo que eu vi no link que você passou, o que você poderia fazer é adicionar isso:

**usando a propriedade flex (futuro do CSS rs)**

```
.navbar-top > .menu1 >ul.navbar-right { 
    height: 101px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**usando a forma antiga (como table)**

```
.navbar-top > .menu1 >ul.navbar-right { 
    height: 101px;
    display: table;
}

.navbar-top > .menu1 >ul.navbar-right li a {
    height: 101px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Além disso, em termos de design você colocando aquele procurar ali oculto vai te atrapalhar quanto aos tamanhos de media queries. o melhor a fazer seria você inserir ele dentro do navbar como um `li` e em aberto, assim além de não ocupar memória para as animações, seu design já fica tratado quando o bootstrap se adaptar e ficar com o menu menor.